# I need to update rows in a table with information in other rows in the same table

Tags: sql-update, ssms

For instance, a row contains a customer number column and a bill to customer number column and a salesperson code column.  Customer number column would be 6519 and the bill to number column has a 56519 (the number 5 is placed in front of the customer number to create the bill to number) . There is a separate row for each bill to customer in the same table where the salesperson code is blank.  I want to update the bill to customer rows with the same salesperson code that is in the customer number row.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table to itself using the columns that relate to each other and perform an update in this manner.  You may need to update the table and column names to match the ones you're using, but an example of this is below.

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.SalesPersonCode = T2.SalesPersonCode
FROM dbo.YourTableName T1
INNER JOIN dbo.YourTableName T2 ON T1.CustomerNumber = T2.BillToCustomerNumber
```

Comment: This is it I'm sure but it does the opposite of what I want to do.  It copies the current bill to customers associated salesperson code where the bill to customer number exists.

Comment: The columns were just mis-matched.  I updated my answer accordingly.